# How to do a dynamic dropdown using Ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I know this may be the [insertLongNumber]th time someone's ask this question, I did my research but I can't find another answer that fits my problem. So here it is.

I'm working on a dynamic dropdown with php and ajax, in codeigniter. I'm new to CI and I have a basic knowledge of Ajax.

What I have noticed so far is that in the console, it is not recognizing the value coming from the first dropdown, so i get departamento_id : undefined
This makes me thing problem comes from ajax script (i got it of the web)

My view, with the ajax code included

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('html'); 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Buscador</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dpto-dropdown select').change(function () {
                var selDpto = $(this).attr('value');
                console.log(selDpto);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test/ajax_call",
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "departamento_id="+selDpto,
                    dataType: "html",

                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#ciudad').html(data);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<?php echo form_open('test/buscar');?>

<?php 

<div id='dpto-dropdown'><?php print form_dropdown('departamentos', $departamento) ?></div>


<div id="ciudad"><select><option value=''>-</option></select></div>
//rest of code...
```

This is my Controller code:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('buscador_model');
}   

function index()
{
    $departamentos = $this->buscador_model->traerInfoDptos();
    $precios = $this->buscador_model->traerPrecioHoteles();

    foreach($departamentos as $departamento){
        $dpto_final[$departamento->id] = $departamento->nom_departamento;
    }

    $info = array(
        'departamento' => $dpto_final,
        'precios' => $precios,
    ); 

    $this->load->view('buscador_view', $info);
}

function ajax_call()
{
    //check to see people wont go directly
    if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['departamento_id'])) 
    {
        $dpto = $_POST['departamento_id'];
        $ciudad = $this->buscador_model->traerCiudadPorDpto($dpto);

        foreach ($ciudad as $c)
        {
            $ciudadfinal[$c->cod_ciudad] = $c->nom_ciudad;
        }

        //dropdown

        echo form_dropdown('Ciudades', $ciudadfinal);
    }
    else 
    {
        redirect('index');
    }
}
}
```

this is my model:

```
Class Buscador_model extends CI_Model
{

function traerInfoDptos()
{
    $this->db->select('id, nom_departamento');
    $this->db->from('departamento');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
}

function traerCiudadPorDpto($dpto)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT nom_ciudad, cod_ciudad FROM ciudad WHERE departamento_id = '{$dpto}'");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
}

}// end buscador model class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this page: http://www.onerutter.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-tips-how-to-get-value-of-selected-option-in-select-box.html

You need to use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dpto-dropdown select').change(function () {

            var selDpto = $(this).val(); // <-- change this line
            console.log(selDpto);

            $.ajax({
                url: "test/ajax_call",
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                data: "departamento_id="+selDpto,
                dataType: "html",

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ciudad').html(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesnt work, there's no longer a problem with value, but I still don't see my second dropdown. Could it be a problem in my ajax_call function?

Comment: could be, what do you get when you do a `console.log(data);` in your `success` callback?

Comment: I get this:

`<html>
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Kai Oswald Seidler">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<title>XAMPP 1.7.7</title>

<frameset rows="74,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" borderwidth="0">
    <frame name="head" src="head.php" scrolling=no>
<frameset cols="150,*" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" borderwidth="0">
    <frame name="navi" src="navi.php" scrolling=no>
    <frame name="content" src="start.php" marginwidth=20>
</frameset>
</frameset>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>
</body>
</html>´

Comment: just fixed it, there was an error with the url "text/ajax_call". I put the complete path instead (http://localhost/../text/ajax_call). Thanks for your help @swatkins!